# How to debug the script in new popup window in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, popup, google-chrome-devtools

All:

What I want to do is to add a breakpoint to script in a popup window when it is loaded.

For example:

```
index.html

<a target="_blank" href="popupwindow.html">Open new popup window</a> 

popupwindow.html
<script>
    console.log("Start loading");
    // Could anyone show me how to break at the debugger line?
    debugger; 
    alert("finished");
</script>
```

I want to click the link in index.html and popupwindow can stop at the debugger line, could anyone help? **I am using Chrome42.**